# uploadify get total number of files in queue before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `auto: false` in uploadify settings, the upload will start when submit button get clicked, and then once the `onQueueComplete` event fired the form will get submit. however, when there is no files selected, the `onQueueComplete` event did not fired.

so, I need to know how many files selected by user, if 0 then submit the form straight away.

Answer (score 2):

Solved using `$('.uploadify-queue-item').length`. thank you SO.